# How to send user input from TextField to GET method API without body? - Dart

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have a feedback form like this
[image]
the API for it using a GET method without body. I have to send user input from the 3 `TextField` (Nama, Email, Pesan Anda) to GET method API.
[image]
I'm clueless, my senior said that I have to use url parameters so I can still send data to API without a body.
How can I do that?

Comment: what is using at http or dio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP GET method has no body on it's requisitions, so yes, the only way to send params is in the url, where you can send like this:

```
http://{URL}/?nama=Nama&email=Email&pesanAnda=PesanAnda
```

then you API will have access to these params.